# restricting access to dev server

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, linux-networking

We have a development server for our website hosted on our public cloud. We want to block access to it from the outside and only allow access from our public IP. How would I set up the IP tables on the server to accomplish this? this is a centOS server

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments because I'm new here, so excuse me if this breaks the rules.

You didn't specify which version of Centos you are using. Despite the fact you mentioned IP Tables, suggesting an earlier version, I'm going to assume you have either Centos 7 or 8, both of which use firewalld rather than iptables.

This answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7) will help you limit access to your development server.

I run all my servers on Centos 7 and use firewalld to Geo-Block countries which have given me grief from hackers and it works fast and efficiently for me. Similarly there are a couple of IP Addresses individually allowed access.

If you are running an older version of Centos you will need to set up IP Tables, which I cannot help with as my Linux experience started with Centos 7 and 8. My suggestion would be to upgrade Centos to a newer version as older ones have reached their end of life support.

I hope this is helpful to you.